# The Resource cannot be found error in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Movies/Random

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.3928.0

This is an Error Message Shown when I Started doing an online tutorial. What may be the reason for this???

Random.cshtml

```
@model Vidly.Models.Movie
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Random";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

Movie.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MoviesController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Movies/Random
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var movie = new Movie() { Name = "Hello" };

            return View(movie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not pointing on the correct path for your application. The engine is trying to find a action method called `Random` in your `Movies` controller and appranently it is not there. Please review how you have setup your  routes in `RouteConfig.cs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MoviesController.cs it should be

```
public ActionResult Random()
```

instead of

```
public ActionResult Index()
```

Comment: I Changed the URL but the same error occurred. When we use /Movies/Index, the view name is Random.cshtml. To get out of the error either it should be changed to index.cshtml  or the action result should be Random. I went for the latter. By simply changing the URL does not yield the correct output. Anyway thanks for the suggestion and thanks for helping. I learned a lot from this silly mistake.